# How To Pass Parameters From A User Into An Endpoint To Process Logic From User Input

Tags: python, rest, flask, client

So I have a Python script that sends a get request to an API and returns information. For educational purposes, I wanted to create an API that I could pass parameters to which would return results from that script. I couldn't really find a similar example on stackoverflow or on the official flask documentation for an example that meets what I'm looking for. Everything I'm seeing is for returning data that you already have existing in a database or in a json file.

Here's an example of the script that I have right now.

```
script.py

api_url = www.statetaxes.com

parameters = {"taxinfo": "state:Texas county:soaker_county zip_code:78331"}

token = "abcd123456"

response= request.get(api_url, params=parameters, headers={"authentication":token})
print(response.json()) >----- [{tax rate: 1.5%, education_quality:great, crime_rate:0}]
```

The user would set the parameters in a config file somewhere like so:

```
[taxinfo]
county: some_county
zip_code: 12345
```

I'd want to read that text file, grab those parameters and push it to an API endpoint. I can figure out the part on how to read those parameters and send it to the API, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to be configuring the rest of my FLASK app. I'd assume that I'd have to take those parameters which I'm reading from the text file as an argument. Am I on the right path here?

```
@app.route('/taxes/<taxinfo>', methods = ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT' ])
def state_taxes(taxinfo):
    def api_call():

        api_url = www.statetaxes.com

        parameters=taxinfo

        token = "abcd123456"

        response= request.get(api_url, params=parameters, headers={"authentication":token})
    
        
    return api_call

if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Search for "query parameters" and "JSON arguments".

Comment: why is there a code of api_call inside the API itself ? and the route dan't return the method, it should at least do `reutnr api_call()`

Comment: @azro So I was just creating a mock up of how I think it would work. Now that I know to look for "query parameters", I at least have an idea of what direction to go from here. Thanks!

Comment: @flakes Thank you! I think I've found some good resources to help me out.